# Get vocabulary name from vid function

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to extract the vocabulary's name from it's vid. Is there a function that does that or do I have to create it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the vocabulary object using [`taxonomy_vocabulary_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_load/7) and get the name that way:

```
$vid = 1; // Vocabulary ID
$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($vid);
$vocab_name = $vocab->name;
```

Comment: nice, also found out that i could use: $vocabs = taxonomy_get_vocabularies(); and $vocabs[$vid]->name; :)